# Why object required error is showing in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I am using vbscript for automating excel. I know to use excel i need to create object of Excel application.
I have created an object of Excel but still its throwing an error Object required.

> Error picture
> [Object required Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HJat.png)

Here's my code :

```
setInputPath = "C:\Users\pr.ch\Desktop\Blank_Process\Data\"
'setInputPath = Wscript.Arguments(0)


'YESTERDAY DATE -------------------------------------------------------------------------
yesterday = DateAdd("d", -1, Date())
sp = split(yesterday,"/")

d = sp(1)
m = sp(0)
y = sp(2)
if Len(d)= 1 Then
    d = "0" & d
End if  

m = MonthName(m, True)

todayDateAsFolder = d & "-" & m & "-" & y 


FileName = setInputPath & "Output\" & todayDateAsFolder & ".xlsx"
pathCBS = setInputPath & "Input\Makuri\" & todayDateAsFolder & ".xlsx"
pathIB = setInputPath & "Input\iBank\" & todayDateAsFolder & ".xlsx"
pathMM = setInputPath & "Input\MobileMoney\" & todayDateAsFolder & ".xlsx"
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xl.Visible = True
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
Set ws = wb.WorkSheets("CBS")
Set wsiBank = wb.WorkSheets("iBank")
Set wsMobM = wb.WorkSheets("MM")


Set zz = xl.Workbooks.Open(pathCBS)
Set wsCBS = zz.Worksheets(1)

Set wbIB = xl.Workbooks.open(pathIB)
Set wsIB = wbIB.worksheets(1)

Set wbMM = xl.Workbooks.open(pathMM)
Set wsMM = wbMM.worksheets(1)



'Count CBS totalRows and totalColumn-------------------------------------------------------------
totalRowsCBS = wsCBS.UsedRange.Rows.Count
totalColCBS = wsCBS.usedRange.Columns.Count
wsCBS.Range("A1:" & Chr(totalColCBS + 64) & totalRowsCBS).Copy
ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial


'Count IBANK toalRows and totalColumn ----------------------------------------------------------
totalRowsIB = wsIB.UsedRange.Rows.Count
totalColIB = wsIB.usedRange.Columns.Count
wsIB.Range("A1:" & Chr(totalColIB + 64) & totalRowsIB).Copy
wsiBank.Range("A1").PasteSpecial


'Count MM toalRows and totalColumn --------------------------------------------------------------
totalRowsMM = wsMM.UsedRange.Rows.Count
totalColMM = wsMM.usedRange.Columns.Count
wsMM.Range("A1:" & Chr(totalColMM + 64) & totalRowsMM).Copy
wsMobM.Range("A1").PasteSpecial


wb.Save
wb.Close
xl.Quit

'msgbox "Completed 06"
```

I tried creating new excel object for every sheets that i am working on which is working but not as expected. I am using VBs from 3 months never ever i encountered this error.

Comment: Could you check the value of `zz` before using it? It could be Null.

Comment: zz is an object, reference to workbook path

Comment: Does the `pathCBS` variable location exists? Chances are the error is related to not finding the file to open.

Comment: Would also recommend using `Option Explicit` at the top of the script to guarantee every variable is declared and isn’t suffering from scoping issues.

Comment: i have given right path,

Comment: I have used "Option Explicit" at top of my script but its showing : variable is undefined : 'setInputPath'.

I have declared the variable already but why its showing weird error !

Comment: But yet showing object required error on same line